# Is the Aldori Dueling Sword viable as a Swashbuckler weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, swashbuckler

So, the title question sort of says it all. I just need some clarification.

The wording for the Swashbucklers Panache ability specifically states several times that in order to regain Panache you must "Confirm a critical hit/Score a killing blow" with a "Light ***OR*** One-Handed Piercing weapon"

By utilizing [Slashing Grace](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Slashing%20Grace) is the [Aldori Dueling Sword](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Aldori%20dueling%20sword) viable for Swashbuckler? Given the wording, I would say yes, but the Dueling sword is classified as a Heavy Blade, which gives me pause.

I understand that the scimitar is usually the focus of Slashing Grace, but thematically I like the dueling sword for this character, does it restrict any abilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Slashing Grace, yes, a swashbuckler may use an Aldori dueling sword and still regain panache.

1. The Aldori dueling sword is a one-handed slashing melee weapon.
2. Slashing Grace says that a one-handed slashing melee weapon may count as a one-handed *piercing* melee weapon “for all feats and class abilities that require such a weapon.”
3. Regaining panache is a “class ability that require[s]” a one-handed piercing melee weapon.